# How do I query data using the Element API Plugin based on a custom field?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I have a channel called "offers".

My Offers channel contains a field called "Users".

The Users field is the "users" field type. It allows me to select 1 or more users that the Offer is for.

I want to get JSON output for this data based on the "Users" name.

```
'users/<username:{handle}>/offers.json' => function($username) {
            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => ['section' => 'specialOffers', 'relatedTo' => $username],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'category' => $entry->category->label,

                ];
              },
            ];
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re close. But the `relatedTo` param can’t just be set to some username. It has to either be an element ID or an actual element model (more specifically, a user ID or UserModel in this case).

```php
'users/<username:{handle}>/offers.json' => function($username) {
    // Get the actual user model
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('User');
    $criteria->username = $username;
    $user = $criteria->first();

    // If there was no user, return no results
    if (!$user) {
        return [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['id' => false],
        ];
    }

    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'specialOffers',
            'relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => $user]
        ],
        // ...
    ];
},
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! Thank you so much!!! This was it! I didn't realize the relatedTo param had to be an element ID or an actual element model.

Comment: Is there any way to get the results of a matrix as well? I have a matrix block inside my Entry. I can query the first result on a matrix block in the entry by doing: $entry->mileage->first()->miles. However, I need to get it based on the User. Any suggestions?